# Using breakpoints to debug Javascript in IE and VS2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

I am not able to use the breakpoint in Studio with Javascript.  I'm able to debug if I use the debugger;

I've seen this [Breakpoint not hooked up when debugging in VS.Net 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163133/breakpoint-not-hooked-up-when-debugging-in-vsnet-2005) question already.  I tried the answer and it didn't work.

Looking in the Modules window, V.Mvc.Jobtrakt.PDB is loaded properly, but it points to a temp folder 
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\dbc0c0c5\f64a99b3\assembly\dl3\9de055b3\eb1303b1_9760c901\V.Mvc.Jobtrak.pdb: Symbols loaded.

I would have thought that it would point to: 
  \JobTrak\Website\V.Mvc.Jobtrak\V.Mvc.Jobtrak\obj\Debug ( this is within the project directory)

But regardless of the location I closed VS 2008 and then blew away the temp folder (listed above), the bin and obj folders.

Opened VS 2008 and did a clean.  I set a break point in the js and it seemed like it would work now ( The breakpoint was filled in)
Started to debug and it never breaks on the breakpoint. Look at the break point and it now is a red circle with a red dot and a warning indicator.  Hovering over the breakpoint gives me this useful information: The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The location could not be mapped to a client side script. See help for ASPX Breakpoint mapping. I am not being redirected, the breakpoint is with in a function. blah blah blah this should be working.

So I was wondering if anyone has any ideas? 
Is anyone able to set breakpoints in VS2008 and have them work?

Comment: I can add "debugger" to the javascript to force it to break.  I'm trying to get the breakpoints to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try typing "debugger" in the source where you want to break

Comment: Good call Greg.  That one is a definite fast track to the debugger.

Comment: This does work.  I was trying to get the breakpoints to work.

Comment: Yikes, Only 6 years later to accept. Apparently this still works :)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are attached to the correct process.  For example, once you have your page loaded in IE,

1. Switch to Visual Studio and go to the Debug menu.
2. Choose "Attach to Process"
3. Find iexplore in the list and select it.
4. Click the "Select..." button.
5. In the dialog, choose "Debug these code types:" and select **only** "Script".
6. Click "OK"
7. Click "Attach"

See if that helps get you debugging javascript.

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me also. The breakpoints stopped to work in some functions. In my case, the problem was that I used `<%=..%>` inside the script. As far as I could figure out reading MSDN, this happens because Visual Studio maps the breakpoint lines from the `.ASPX` to the resulting HTML based on line content, so when you put a `<%=..>` your resulting script will be different from the one in the `.ASPX` file.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to put debugger in the javascript. I had this happen and the reason was there was an error in the script in a try catch block in terms of syntax. As soon as I fixed the syntax, breakpoints mapped correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

Greg answered the question, however just to add some more value to answer -

Put debugger in the java script code.

As well make sure you have debugger enabled in the internet explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Advance

the check boxes for disabled debugging should not be checked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, was due I was using

$.ajax({
                type: "GET",

instead
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",...

Comment: Your two lines are identical? What is the difference supposed to be?

Answer (score -1):

Just type alert function in script for each line or any line, if the alert is not triggered then we can identify the line where its through the error

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() {
    //event handler to the checkbox selection change event
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        //variables to store the total price of selected rows
        //and to hold the reference to the current checkbox control
        var totalPrice = 0, ctlPrice;
        //iterate through all the rows of the gridview
        $('#Grid2 tr').each(function() {
        //if the checkbox in that rows is checked, add price to our total proce
            alert("Hi")
            if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked")) {
                ctlPrice = $(this).find('[id$= lblPackAmount]');
                //since it is a currency column, we need to remove the $ sign and then convert it
                //to a number before adding it to the total
                totalPrice += parseFloat(ctlPrice.text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
            }
        });
        //finally set the total price (rounded to 2 decimals) to the total paragraph control.
        //alert(totalPrice);
        $('#lblAmount').text(totalPrice);               
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is all this code? Does this have anything to do with the question?