# why are breakpoints not hit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I am trying to run the debugger in my vs.net 2010 asp.net 3.5 app on iis 7 on my machine.

the breakpoints are set and loaded but are not hit? I also have a url rewriter httpmodule loaded.

Comment: The most common reason is your binary and source are misaligned. Try cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: Another possible reason is that your breakpoint are in code that is running on another process. Select debug and choose Attach to process if this is the case.

Comment: Are you building in debug mode or release mode?

Comment: in debugmode: tried cleaning and rebuilding

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301216/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-d  and http://www.shubho.net/2010/08/why-breakpoint-does-not-hit-in-visual.html

Comment: Is it running on a separate thread?

Comment: Are all breakpoints not being hit or is it just specific ones?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was debugging my project, and i had to right click the project and select "new debug instance". I only needed to do this once, then after that it worked as normal.