# Object reference not set to an instance of an object...Error?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, event-handling, sharepoint-list, event-receiver

Ok so I totally new to C# and am trying to debug an error. Basically I am trying to create an EventReceiver for a SharePoint List...this is the code that is giving me the object reference error when I am debugging:

```
   public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdding(properties);

       SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;

       if (item["Name"] == null)
           return; //or better yet, log 

       string oldFileName = item["Name"].ToString();
```

What I am doing is entering Debug mode, and selecting to add a file to a SharePoint library (this is in ItemAdding event), now this error is shown after I select the file I want to upload, any idea why?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should **tag** this question with `sharepoint`

Comment: Are you sure that `properties.ListItem` is not null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an "object reference error", it's a `NullReferenceException` caused by the fact that you are trying access the index operator of `item`, which is `null`.

You could have found this out by setting a breakpoint in the line of the `if` statement and hovering your mouse over the different variables.

To fix this, make sure `properties.ListItem` contains a non-null value or insert another check in your if:

```
if (item == null || item["Name"] == null)
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work, I tried using breakpoints, however, as soon as I enter debug mode my breakpoint turns yellow and hovering over it I get the message "Breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document" any idea why this is?

Comment: @TudorHofnar try to keep it running eventually the symbols will be loaded and the breakpoint will be hit.

Comment: There's a [relevant SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301216/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-d) that offers a few possible solutions.

Comment: @StanR. I left it running for about 10 min and the break points still haven't loaded (while I was replying to emails haha)

Comment: @codesparkle I had a read through that thread and tried a few of the option but nothin worked. 
Right click on solution --> Properties

Look under Common Properties --> Startup Project

Select multiple startup projects

select Start action on the projects you need to debug.

That solution in particular I can't perform since I can't find Common Properties, I am doing all this in an Even Receiver project. Any idea how I can try that out?

Answer (score 0):

You probably got the error because `SPListItem item` is null. You cannot acces to null variable. You may try to update your code to:

```
       SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;

       if (item == null || item["Name"] == null) 
           return; //or better yet, log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
System.Debug.Assert(item != null, "item is null.");


if (item["Name"] == null) --DEBUGGER STOPS HERE
    return; //or better yet, log
```

it seems that `item` or more specific `properties.ListItem` is null!
<del>As `item` is just a reference.</del>

Comment: `properties.ListItem` and `item` are *both* references.