# How to set a breakpoint

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

So I'm trying to set a breakpoint in a WP8 app, but once the app is running under the debugger (on both a physical device and in the emulator), my breakpoint turns white with the following rollover message:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

I am running a standard debug build. In the project settings, I can see that both debugger types (UI Task and Agent Task) are both set to "Managed Only". Under Build->Advanced, I can see that "Debug Info" is set to "Full".

If I place the statement:

```
Debugger.Break()
```

then I break out correctly.

What do I have to do to set breakpoints from the IDE?

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301216/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-d .In the first it seems to be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following steps

- Right click on the '**Solution**'
- Select **Properties**
- From the property window expand the **Common Properties** from left side and select **Startup Project**
- select **multiple startup projects** from the 3 options.
- select the project you want to debug and in the **action** select **start** from the drop down.