# Debugging Webservice "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded"

Tags: asp.net, web-services, silverlight, debugging

I'm trying to debug something on a Silverlight Webservice.

It was initially set up to work with IIS, which was working, but I figured it would be easier to debug on the VS development server so I switched to that.

Debugging the silverlight part works fine, but when I put a breakpoint in the webservice (the .csv.cs) it doesn't get hit, coming up with:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document

I've tried:

- Clean solution & rebuild
- Deleted obj and bin folders, rebuilt
- Ensure you are in debug mode. No code optimisation
- ASP.NET and Silverlight debugger selected.
- Deleted the temporary ASP.NET generated assembly files for the project
  under “C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework{framework
  version}\Temporary ASP.NET Files”
- Using IIS server and attaching debugger manually
- Created new IIS web app from scratch
- deleted the solution suo file
- rebooted the machine
- Updated IE browser from 8 to 11
- Checked Physical directory is pointing in the right place (Seems to be) and that all .pdb files are up to date/being created on build
- disabled "just my code"
- Loaded symbols for all modules

In the "Multiple start up projects" settings for the solution I've got the actions as "None" for the Silverlight app, and "Start" for the Webservice.

In configuration, both are configured for "Debug" on any CPU and have "Build" checked.

Build output:

```
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\WebDev.WebHost40\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\WebDev.WebHost40.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\mscorlib.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\System.Windows.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\System.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\System.Net.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\System.Core.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\System.Xml.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\System.Windows.Browser.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\en-US\System.debug.resources.dll'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'BAE', Symbols loaded.
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'InfragisticsSL5.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.v14.1'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'InfragisticsSL5.Controls.Editors.XamColorPicker.v14.1'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'InfragisticsSL5.Controls.Editors.XamSlider.v14.1'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'InfragisticsSL5.DataVisualization.v14.1'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'InfragisticsSL5.v14.1'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Web'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.ServiceModel.Web.Extensions'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.Windows.Controls'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.Windows.Controls.Input'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.Xml.Linq'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.ComponentModel.Composition'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.Initialization'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.Windows.Data'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\System.ServiceModel.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'BindingDebugging'
'iexplore.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\en-US\System.Windows.debug.resources.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0x20f0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1154) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b58) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1ea4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1fc0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x23f8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Any tips on what to try next? Thanks

Comment: there's a ton of suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301216/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-d

Comment: Great! Hadn't found that one.

Comment: None of them seemed to resolve the issue, bar the transfer over to new project, or re-install VS...