# Break Points not responding when using IIS for Web Application VS2010 C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, webforms

I Have a couple of apps that have the same problem, I need to run those in IIS.
(I go to Properties, Web, and assign Start URL as https://mycomputername.com/ProjectName/), it runs correctly, however if I set a break point, it will never stop there.

The breakpoints always read:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

My solution is located at the wwwroot, and I run Visual Studio 2010. If I switch from Start URL to Specific Page, the breakpoints work again. But I need the Start URL since there are some functions in my solution that only work that way.

I know that there are other solutions I have that are also being run on IIS and don't have this issue. The only difference I notice from the other projects that could be relevant is that those are WebSites in VS 2010, while mine is a Web Project.

Projects with this icon do work
[image]

My project with this icon does not
[image]

I have already messed around with the Tools->Options->Debugging->General. No success

Debug->Break All->. No success

Any ideas on how could I get this fixed?

Comment: Have you tried Attach To Process?

Comment: I think I did, however I do not remember what went wrong...
What process should I look for?

Comment: IIS runs a process called w3wp.exe for each running site. If you only have one, then that's it. If you have multiple, you can find scripts that will tell you which process is for which site. By the way, VS 2010 is 5 years old. It's slow and not nearly as full featured as VS 2013 or 2015. You might consider upgrading...

Comment: I think I solved it...
Indeed it's that process you mention, however last time it did not show up, this time, I figured if I checked Show processes in all sessions, it showed up this time...

Comment: Apparently, even thought that solves the problem, now every time I stop the app, I have to re attach the exe...
Is there a way for the project to keep that process attached permanently?

Comment: Not that I know of. Why are you required to run it in IIS anyways? Why not use Visual Studio's built in server?

Comment: I requiere a validation that can only be accessed from a server in my company, and I was told that it has to run on IIS to get that to work, since in localhost it will never catch it

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by "a validation"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301216/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-d)

Comment: I need to get a loginID from a variable like this
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LoginID"]...
It only works when I run it on IIS