# debugging does not stop at break point

Tags: asp.net

in my project i insert break point in my c# file the debugger check the whole file gives output but it doesnot stop at the break point and as aresult i could not check the error in it plz if anybody know the answer mail me at jagdeepgupta813@gmail.com

Comment: Is that a button click event you have that brakepoint

Comment: This is a forum for question and answer, where people ask questions & expect answer to be posted. Don't expect people to email answers to you. You will have to come to the shop to buy things. No home deliveries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some questions:

- Did you build the project in Debug mode?
- Did you "start with debugging" (F5 instead of Ctrl+F5)
- in web.config, do you have debug=true in the `<compilation>` node?

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to the code not being the same version as the assembly.

Have a look at this link

[Breakpoint not hooked up when debugging in VS.Net 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163133/breakpoint-not-hooked-up-when-debugging-in-vs-net-2005)