# Breakpoint not hooked up when debugging in VS 2008 sp1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

My project has a lot of static library (with sources).
Some base libraries can't be breakpointed because the source code is different from the original version.
I know I can workaround if I turn off "Require source files to exactly match the original version" option, but that warning makes me worry.
Is it Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 bug?
I heard it happen when checksum of source code is different with obj.
I have all sources of library and linked as static library,
I cleaned and rebuilt all, but warning never disappeared.

What a worse is, when I turn off "Require source files to exactly match the original version" option, watch windows can't show what member variable has with this error "FIX: CXX0033 Error in OMF Type from Forward Class Declaration"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131147/en-us?fr=1

I searched stack overflow and find several similar article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163133/breakpoint-not-hooked-up-when-debugging-in-vs-net-2005) but those couldn't help me.

Environment :
Windows 2003 server x64
Visual Studio 2008 sp1 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your symbols and sources search paths to ensure they include the right folders with the static library. Check that y7ou are linking the .lib and the .obj files from the right directory. Also, break in program under the debugger, and check where are the symbols for the library loaded from - they should be from the same folder the .obj and the .lib came from.

Comment: How can I see where symbols and sources search paths are? Anyway thanks.

Comment: Tools / Options / Debug (I think)

Comment: I found this link and it works. After some experiment, I will post the result.
"An attempt to create a debugging library that uses precompiled headers may fail, and fatal build errors may be generated"
http://www.kbalertz.com/102697/Build-Errors-Using-Precompiled-Header-Debugging.aspx